# Convert the content of pdf files to QIF/QFX/OFX

Tags: pdf, ofx, gnucash, qif

I'm currently looking for some piece of software that could accept a pdf file with my bank statements (since I apparently cannot obtain a csv file) and convert its content into a .OFX/.QFX/.QFI file that I could work with inside of something like Homebank or GNUCash. Does anyone know of anything that does this (ideally working on Linux, specifically Void)?